# Redeem SSL certificate from go daddy for a .app domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, github-pages, godaddy-api

I recently acquired a .app domain from godaddy and it was stated that ssl certificate is included. The instructions says you must go to myproducts page to redeem and activate the included ssl certificate. The problem is I can't seem to figure how , as there is nothing about ssl on the myproducts page and additional products (at the bottom of the my products page) says there was a problem retrieving additional products. Please how do I claim my ssl certificate?

Answer (score 1):

After much fiddling, I found out that I need to update my card details (debit card). Once I did, the ssl certificate appeared on the my products page under additional products.